# Proving $A \to \exists x B(x) \therefore \exists x(A \to B(x))$

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 297, exercise C. 2), appears the following exercise:

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{A \to \exists x B(x)}{
   \fitch{\neg \exists x(A \to B(x))}{
     \fitch{A}{
       \exists xB(x)\\
         \fitch{B(c)}{
           \ldots
         }
       }
     }
 }
$

The next step would be to use Repetition rule in order to derive $B(c)$ but that move is forbidden since $c$ appears in an undischarged assumptions. How can I continue the proof?

Comment: Can't you next conclude $A\to B(c)$.(here c is merely a witness from you existential instantiation), and then $\exists (A\to B(x))$, discharges c.  I assume that is what you want, because then you derive a contradiction from your first assumption.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I should make clear $A$ is an additional assumption. Just edited the post. I cannot conclude $A \to B(c)$, since $B(c)$ is nested inside the subproof that starts by assuming $A$.

Comment: Just a note, not directly helpful, but we, (or at least I) very much appreciate the quality of your questions and the time you take to present them well.

Comment: Thank you so much, @amWhy. You just made my day with your comment.

Comment: Thank you, @MauroALLEGRANZA. Will take another path to this proof.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, could you give me another hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a proof here ... but the OP's eventual version at the end of the comments below is snappier and to be preferred!!

Comment: Thank you, @PeterSmith. I am only allowed to use basic rules of TFL and quantifiers. I do not understand how do you derive $A \to B(c)$ from the assumption of $\neg A$.

Comment: Given $\neg A$ you can infer $A \to C$ for any $C$. This is absolutely basic bookwork. For given $\neg A$ start a subproof headed with the new supposition $A$. You now have a contradiction, so can infer any $C$. So supposition $A$ yields $C$, so discharge the supposition to get $A \to C$.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterSmith. Would be something like this ? $$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{A \to \exists x B(x)}{
  \fitch{\neg \exists x(A \to B(x))}{
   \fitch{\neg A}{
     \fitch{A}{
       \bot\\
       B(c)\\
     }\\
     A \to B(c)\\
     \exists x(A \to B(x))\\
     \bot\\
   }\\
   \ldots\\
   \bot
 }\\
 \exists x(A \to B(x))
}
$$

Comment: Yes! Though at the end you should [in standard systems] derive $\neg\neg\exists x(A \to B(x))$, and then use the double negation rule.

Comment: Thank you ! How can I fill the dots ? I cannot think a way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed proof, @PeterSmith. Would be possible to shorten the proof doing this? $$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{A \to \exists xB(x)}{
 \fitch{\neg \exists x(A \to B(x))}{
   \fitch{A}{
       \exists xB(x)\\
       \fitch{B(c)}{
         \fitch{A}{
           B(c)
         }\\
         A \to B(c)\\
         \exists x(A \to B(x))\\
         \bot\\
       }\\
       \bot\\
       B(c)\\
     }\\
     A \to B(c)\\
     \exists x(A \to B(x))\\
     \bot 
   }\\
   \exists x(A \to B(x))
 }
$$

Comment: Yes that's much better .... what WAS I thinking of, a senior moment here!

Answer (score 1):

One very nice feature of natural deduction is that the quantifier rules are just generalizations of the propositional rules.  For example,
$$\begin{array} {c}
\dfrac{A \lor B,~ A \to X,~ B \to X}{X} \\
\\
\text{ Generalizes to } \\
\\
\dfrac{A_0 \lor A_1 \lor A_2 \cdots,~ A_0 \to X,~ A_1 \to X,~ A_2 \to X,~ \cdots}{X} \\
\\
\text{ Generalizes to } \\
\\
\dfrac {\exists x . Ax,~ A_k \to X}{X} \\
\end{array}$$

And this is useful, because to get an idea how to prove $A \to \exists x . Bx \vdash \exists x . (A \to Bx)$, first prove $A \to (B_0 \lor B_1) \vdash (A \to B_0) \lor (A \to B_1)$, then generalize everything to quantifiers.

And you should be able to prove every true boolean tautology methodically, algorithmically, no intuition required.  This is what completeness proofs are for.  Just do a separate case for all $2^n$ possible variable assignments and combine them all with or-elimination:

$$\boxed{\begin{array} {ll}
A \to (B_0 \lor B_1) \\
A \lor \lnot A & \text{Law of excluded middle} \\
B_0 \lor \lnot B_0 \\
B_1 \lor \lnot B_1 \\
\\
\text{(Here we have 8 "cases" of variables to do or-elimation on)} \\
\\
\text{First the cases where B_0 asserted} \\
\quad ?A \land B_0 \land ?B_1 & \text{Assumption} \\
\quad B_0 & \land \text{ elimination } \\
\quad A \to B_0 & \text { Weakening } \\
\quad (A \to B_0) \lor (A \to B_1)  \\
\\
\text{The cases where B_1 are asserted is handled similarly} \\
\\
\text{Then remaining cases where A holds and B doesn't:} \\
\quad A \land \lnot B_0 \land \lnot B_1 & \text{Assumption} \\
\quad A & \text{And elimination} \\
\quad B_0 \lor B_1 & \text{From theorem's assumption} \\
\\
\quad \quad B_0 & \text{Assumption} \\
\quad \quad (A \to B_0) \lor (A \to B_1) & \text{By contradiction} \\
\\
\quad \quad B_1 & \text{Assumption} \\
\quad \quad (A \to B_0) \lor (A \to B_1) & \text{By contradiction} \\
\\
\quad (A \to B_0) \lor (A \to B_1) & \lor \text{ Elimination} \\
\\
\text{The final case where all variables are false:} \\
\quad \lnot A \land \lnot B_0 \land \lnot B_1 \\
\quad \quad A & \text {Assumption} \\
\quad \quad B_0 & \text {By contradiction} \\
\quad A \to B_0  \\
\quad (A \to B_0) \lor (A \to B_1) & \lor \text { introduction} \\
\\
\text{Put all the cases together:} \\
(A \to B_0) \lor (A \to B_1) & \text{Several } \lor \text{ eliminations }
\end{array}}$$

So just generalize that proof to quantifiers:

$$\boxed{\begin{array} {ll}
A \to \exists x . Bx \\
A \lor \lnot A & \text{Law of excluded middle} \\
\exists x . Bx \lor \lnot \exists x . Bx \\
\\
\quad \exists x . Bx & \text{Assumption} \\
\quad \quad Bc & \text{ Assumption } \\
\quad \quad A \to Bc & \text { Weakening } \\
\quad \quad \exists x . A \to Bx \\
\quad \exists x . A \to Bx & \exists \text{ elimination }\\
\\
\quad A \land \lnot \exists x . Bx & \text{Assumption} \\
\quad A & \land \text{ elimination} \\
\quad \exists x . Bx & \text{From theorem's assumption} \\
\quad \exists x. A \to Bx & \text{ from contradiction } \\
\\
\quad \lnot A \land \lnot \exists x.Bx \\
\quad \quad A & \text {Assumption} \\
\quad \quad Bx & \text {By contradiction} \\
\quad A \to Bx  \\
\quad \exists x . A \to Bx & \exists \text { introduction} \\
\\
\exists x . (A \to Bx) & \text{A few } \lor \text{ and } \exists \text{ eliminations }
\end{array}}$$

Anyway the point I'm trying to get across is you can often solve predicate logic problems just by solving the specific propositional logic problem and then generalizing the inferences.  It is a very nice feature of natural deduction.

Comment: I cannot use Law of Excluded Middle but thank you very much for your detailed answer !

Comment: @F.Zer If you can't use it as an inference you can derive it.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielV. Of course, but the book only allows basic TFL rules at this stage — not derived.

Comment: @F.Zer Well that you can't use LEM is someone irrelevant to the main point of the post.  If you use double negation elimination instead, then use that to prove your proposition version and generalize that proof.  You don't have to follow this outline exactly.  It might help you on future problems.

Comment: Of course, @DanielV. I will learn from your proof outline to use it in future problems. Thanks for the time you dedicated to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using another form of natural deduction that does not assume a non-empty universe. A proof by cases, the free variable $x$ is explicitly introduced on line 1.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In your logic, what prevents the following proof: 

$$\begin{array} {rrr} 
(1) & P(x) \to P(x) & \text{By propositional logic} \\ 
(2) & P(x) \to P(x) & \text{ Assumption introducing x} \\ 
(3) & \exists x . (P(x) \to P(x)) & \text{E Gen of 2} \\ 
(4) & (P(x) \to P(x)) \to \exists x . (P(x) \to P(x)) & \text{Discharge assumption 2} \\ 
(5) & \exists x . (P(x) \to P(x)) & \text{ Modus Ponens of 1 and 4}
\end{array}$$

Comment: @DanielV The first line is not a theorem. You could, however, prove $\forall x: [P(x)\to P(x)]$. If we leave it out line 1, you should use another bound variable, say $y$, in line 3. Otherwise, you can't discharge the assumption on line 2. When you discharge  it, your would get $\forall x: [[P(x)\to P(x)] \to \exists y: [P(y)\to P(y)]]$. Then line 5 would not follow.

Comment: Isn't $\bigg(\forall x (Px \to Px)\bigg) \to \bigg(\exists x (Px \to Px)\bigg)$ an assertion of an inhabited universe ?

Comment: @DanielV I do not assume an non-empty universe in my logic. The user can, of course, introduce a free variable as in line 1 of my proof. Then your proof would work if you changed the bound variable on your line 3.

Comment: I don't see how it could possibly be true if you allow empty universes: if $A$ is false and the universe is empty, then $A \rightarrow \exists x B(x)$ is true but $\exists x (A \rightarrow B(x))$ is false.